# Getting started with biclustering

Tags: clustering

I have been doing some casual internet research on biclusters.  (I have read the Wiki article several times.)  So far, it seems as if there are few definitions or standard terminology.

1. I was wondering if there were any standard papers or books that anybody who is interested in algorithms for finding biclusters should read.
2. Is it possible to say what is the state of the art in the field?  I was intrigued by the notion of finding biclusters using genetic algorithms, so I would appreciate comments on that approach in particular in the context of other approaches.
3. Usually in clustering, the goal is to partition the data-set into groups where each element is in some group.  Do bicluster algorithms also seek to put all elements in a particular group?

Note: Also posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7419/seeking-advice-on-getting-started-with-biclustering).  I thought perhaps the larger number of mathematically-inclined eyeballs on here might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a good starting point would be [Tanay, Shamir and Sharan's survey](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.118.8302%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=biclustering%20survey%20shamir&ei=nvRkTeerJsiu8QP0i5XqBg&usg=AFQjCNFx0RLoztVM3pLIiakOx0QvYo694A&sig2=N0fhYThDoa4c8Nia8dbf2A&cad=rja).